# Average sales of last three years using interpolation/extrapolation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, prediction, interpolation, approximate-inference, extrapolation

I have average sales value for the last three years of a company, e.g.

| year | avg. sales |
| --- | --- |
| 2017 | 100 |
| 2018 | 150 |
| 2019 | 200 |

Is it possible to somehow come up with an estimate of total average sales value for the years 2014, 2015, and 2016 combined with a confidence interval assuming that sales follows a normal distribution. If not what other information is required to make such an interpolation/extrapolation?

Answer (score 0):

Well, three years is really not much but, hypothetically speaking, if you had more data, you could use linear regression (if you expect a simple relationship between the year and the sales) or time series analysis (if you expect more complex relationships between sales in different years and/or some hidden factors that influence the sales).